# Can't get Stream 1: EOF reached while reading in Java 11 HTTP/2 Client

Tags: java, httpclient, http2, java-11

I'm currently learning HTTP/2 Client in Java 11(`java.net.http` module)

My purpose is send a `POST` `JSON` data to local server using Java 11 HTTP/2 Client, but I occurred some `IOException`, `EOFException`.

**Exceptions**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Can't get stream 1: java.io.EOFException: EOF reached while reading
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:565)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:119)
    at study/study.Http2ClientSample4.main(Http2ClientSample4.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't get stream 1: java.io.EOFException: EOF reached while reading
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.lambda$checkForUpgradeAsync$12(Exchange.java:486)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1106)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2235)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.lambda$checkForUpgradeAsync$13(Exchange.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1106)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2235)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.checkForUpgradeAsync(Exchange.java:467)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.lambda$wrapForUpgrade$10(Exchange.java:432)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniComposeStage(CompletableFuture.java:1106)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenCompose(CompletableFuture.java:2235)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.wrapForUpgrade(Exchange.java:432)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.sendRequestBody(Exchange.java:399)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.checkFor407(Exchange.java:354)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Exchange.lambda$responseAsyncImpl0$7(Exchange.java:423)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: EOF reached while reading
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.onComplete(Http2Connection.java:1336)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadSubscription.signalCompletion(SocketTube.java:632)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:833)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowTask.run(SocketTube.java:175)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:198)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:271)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:224)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.signalReadable(SocketTube.java:763)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent.signalEvent(SocketTube.java:941)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowEvent.handle(SocketTube.java:245)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:957)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.lambda$run$3(HttpClientImpl.java:912)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:912)
```

**My Code**

```
Path testPath = Paths.get( System.getProperty( "user.dir" ), "jsonSample.txt" );
byte[] testb = Files.readAllBytes( testPath );
System.out.println( new String( testb ) );

HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri( URI.create( "http://localhost:8080" ) )
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header( "Accept", "application/json" )
//              .header( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36" )
                .POST( HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofFile( testPath ) )
                .build();

HttpResponse<?> response = client.send( request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

System.out.println(response.statusCode());
System.out.println(response.body());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does your file `"jsonSample.txt"`includes?

Comment: that file has 
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 21
}

Comment: The above just works fine for me, if I POST it to a sample web service using `URI.create("http://www.example.com/")`, what is the local service actually supposed to do and could it be responsible for the IO exception?

Comment: Oh.. thanks for checking my code. I will check my local erver, and then comment on. Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be because your server does not support HTTP/2. Try adding `version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)` to the HttpRequest

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri( URI.create( "http://localhost:8080" ) )
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .header( "Accept", "application/json" )
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .POST( HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofFile( testPath ) )
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same question, but I find it is occur in random, you can try again and find whether it is occur certainly when you do your request.
If not, you can use try catch to catch this exception and do your request again.