# 'EOF reached while reading' with Spring RestClient and Wiremock using JdkClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: java, spring, wiremock

I keep getting a 'EOF reached while reading' exception trying to write a Wiremock test in my Spring Boot application that uses RestClient.

I managed to write a small reproducer project at https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/restclient-jdk-issue

When you run the `MyGatewayTest`, it fails with:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:57591/something": EOF reached while reading

    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.createResourceAccessException(DefaultRestClient.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchangeInternal(DefaultRestClient.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.retrieve(DefaultRestClient.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.client.support.RestClientAdapter.exchangeForBody(RestClientAdapter.java:73)
    at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceMethod$ExchangeResponseFunction.lambda$create$4(HttpServiceMethod.java:379)
    at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceMethod$ExchangeResponseFunction.execute(HttpServiceMethod.java:336)
    at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceMethod.invoke(HttpServiceMethod.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.service.invoker.HttpServiceProxyFactory$HttpServiceMethodInterceptor.invoke(HttpServiceProxyFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy16.doSomething(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.restclientjdkissue.MyGateway.doSomething(MyGateway.java:15)
    at com.example.restclientjdkissue.MyGatewayTest.testDoSomething(MyGatewayTest.java:27)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: EOF reached while reading
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:964)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:133)
    at org.springframework.http.client.JdkClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(JdkClientHttpRequest.java:102)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:70)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchangeInternal(DefaultRestClient.java:476)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: EOF reached while reading
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection$Http2TubeSubscriber.onComplete(Http2Connection.java:1655)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadSubscription.signalCompletion(SocketTube.java:648)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:853)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowTask.run(SocketTube.java:181)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:207)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:280)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:233)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.signalReadable(SocketTube.java:782)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent.signalEvent(SocketTube.java:965)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowEvent.handle(SocketTube.java:253)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:1467)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.lambda$run$3(HttpClientImpl.java:1412)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:1412)
```

However, if you explicitly configure the `requestFactory` on the `RestClient` to use `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`, then the test is ok:

```
  @Bean
  public RestClient restClient() {
    return RestClient.builder()
        .requestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory())
        .baseUrl(properties.baseUrl())
        .build();
  }
```

I wonder if this is a bug in RestClient, the `JdkClienthttpRequestFactory`, or somewhere else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041856/cant-get-stream-1-eof-reached-while-reading-in-java-11-http-2-client this could be related. Does Wiremock support HTTP2?

Comment: Quick test by me doing `.requestFactory(new JdkClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1).build()))` makes it succeed. Appears that Wiremock doesn't support HTTP2 (or maybe needs to be configured for it?). At least it doesn't response in aa way that would allow the client to downgrade to HTTP 1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JdkClient` by default will use HTTP/2 and normally it will fallback to HTTP/1.1, however apparently wiremock doesn't handle this to well. This is also recorded in [the WireMock issue tracker](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/2459).

When the `JdkClient` is explicitly set to use HTTP/1.1 it works.

```java
@Bean
public RestClient restClient() {
  var client = (HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1).build();
  var requestFactory = new JdkClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
  return RestClient.builder()
      .requestFactory(requestFactory)
      .baseUrl(properties.baseUrl())
      .build();
  }
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041856/cant-get-stream-1-eof-reached-while-reading-in-java-11-http-2-client) regarding the HTTP Client configuration.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/362) HTTP/2 should be supported by Wiremock but it doesn't seem to fallback very good.